# Is it possible to level of microphone audio for automated tests in iOS?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, microphone

a following challenge: we have an iOS app which controls Audio-Hardware over BT. Currently we are doing simple UI automated tests using standard framework. But the idea is this one:

In the app, we control the audio volume with a slider. So pulling the slider to top would increase physical audio volume coming out of the hardware. Theoretically I can get this signal back to iPhone and detect increase or decrease of the volume.

Sounds not difficult but I could not find anyone else in internet doing this stuff. Are there any limitations on microphone usage?